# From what manifold do we need to start to build an eversion for $any$-tridimensional object?

Tags: category-theory, isometry, stiefel-manifolds, higher-homotopy-groups

If a sphere eversion is possible using a half-way model how model is used for $cylinder$ eversion ?

I need to make some premises to be able to frame the true nature of the problem 
In sphere eversion a sphere is transformed through homotopy into a Morin surface.
A half-way model is an immersion of the sphere $S^2$ into $R^3$.
$S^2$ is raised into $^2$ because from [Smale Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmaleTheorem.html) the original sphere come from from $(n − 1)$-dimensional *hyperplane*, so when that 'sphere' (is not a *real* sphere but for simplicity we imagine that it is so) "it goes down" into a standard $R^3$ we have a embedding situation for hyperplane sphere (*such as a group that is a subgroup*).

> The sphere $S^n$ can be turned inside out (more exactly, the standard embedding of $S^n$ into the Euclidean space $R^ {n+1}$ is regularly homotopic to the composition
>   of the standard embedding and of the reflection with respect to an $(n − 1)$ dimensional hyperplane) if and only if $n ∈ {0, 2, 6}$.

This happens because

> classes of immersions of spheres can be realizated using a special group: Regular homotopy group of immersions but with a particular precaution to avoid that $S^2$ sphere in $R^3$ vanishes: the standard embedding and the inside-out one must be *regular* homotopic.

But this is no sufficient because we need that

> their Gauss maps have the same degree/winding number.

But also this is not sufficient because we must have consider homotopy groups of *Stiefel manifolds*. Why Stiefel manifold ?

In other words **real** Stiefel manifold of $\mathbb{R}^k$ of canonical embedding is the coset topological space where the action (*group* action) is via its canonical embedding. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Stiefel+manifold)

I remember that also that

> every finite group G can be embedded in a symmetric group

---

**My question**: from what manifold we need to start to build an eversion for **any**-tridimensional object  ?